# Pandas append perfomance concat/append using "larger" DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

The problem: I have data stored in csv file with the following columns data/id/value. I have 15 files each containing around 10-20mio rows. Each csv file covers a distinct period so the time indexes are non overlapping, but the columns are (new ids enter from time to time, old ones disappear).  What I originally did was running the script without the pivot call, but then I run into memory issues on my local machine (only 8GB). Since there is lots of redundancy in each file, pivot seemd at first a nice way out (roughly 2/3 less data) but now perfomance kicks in. If I run the following script the concat function will run "forever" (I always interrupted manually so far after some time (2h>)). Concat/append seem to have limitations in terms of size (I have roughly 10000-20000 columns), or do I miss something here? Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'D:\\'
data = pd.DataFrame()
#loop through list of raw file names
for file in raw_files:
    data_tmp = pd.read_csv(path + file, engine='c',
                           compression='gzip',
                           low_memory=False,
                           usecols=['date', 'Value', 'ID'])
    data_tmp = data_tmp.pivot(index='date', columns='ID',
                              values='Value')

    data = pd.concat([data,data_tmp])
    del data_tmp
```

EDIT I:To clarify, each csv file has about 10-20mio rows and three columns, after pivot is applied this reduces to about 2000 rows but leads to 10000 columns.

I can solve the memory issue by simply splitting the full-set of ids into subsets and run the needed calculations based on each subset as they are independent for each id. I know it makes me reload the same files n-times, where n is the number of subsets used, but this is still reasonable fast. I still wonder why append is not performing.

EDIT II: I have tried to recreate the file structure with a simulation, which is as close as possible to the actual data structure. I hope it is clear, I didn't spend to much time minimizing simulation-time, but it runs reasonable fast on my machine.

```
import string
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

# Settings :-------------------------------
num_ids = 20000
start_ids = 4000
num_files = 10
id_interval = int((num_ids-start_ids)/num_files)
len_ids = 9
start_date = '1960-01-01'
end_date = '2014-12-31'
run_to_file = 2
# ------------------------------------------

# Simulation column IDs
id_list = []
# ensure unique elements are of size >num_ids
for x in range(num_ids + round(num_ids*0.1)):
    id_list.append(''.join(
        random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _
        in range(len_ids)))
id_list = set(id_list)
id_list = list(id_list)[:num_ids]

time_index = pd.bdate_range(start_date,end_date,freq='D')
chunk_size =  math.ceil(len(time_index)/num_files)

data = []
#  Simulate files
for file in range(0, run_to_file):
    tmp_time = time_index[file * chunk_size:(file + 1) * chunk_size]
    # TODO not all cases cover, make sure ints are obtained
    tmp_ids = id_list[file * id_interval:
        start_ids + (file + 1) * id_interval]

    tmp_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal(
        (len(tmp_time), len(tmp_ids))), index=tmp_time,
        columns=tmp_ids)

    tmp_file = tmp_data.stack().sortlevel(1).reset_index()
    # final simulated data structure of the parsed csv file
    tmp_file = tmp_file.rename(columns={'level_0': 'Date', 'level_1':
                                        'ID', 0: 'Value'})

    # comment/uncomment if pivot takes place on aggregate level or not
    tmp_file = tmp_file.pivot(index='Date', columns='ID',
                              values='Value')
    data.append(tmp_file)

data = pd.concat(data)
# comment/uncomment if pivot takes place on aggregate level or not
# data = data.pivot(index='Date', columns='ID', values='Value')
```

Comment: If you are appending or concating in a loop (and the loop is inevitable), you should at least append the `data_tmp` to a list, and then after the loop concat them all in one time `pd.concat(list_of_all_tmp)`

Comment: That doesn't have a big perfomane impact in that case, the issue arises I think because of the size of the dataframe (both col and row dimensions)

Comment: It will (as it prevents copying a growing dataframe 15 times), if it able to run due to memory. But I am not fully following there. You say you have 15 times 10-20mio rows and 10000-20000 columns, how is this supposed to ever fit in 8GB memory? (A quick calculation says me that it at least in the TBs)

Comment: To make it clear, the original csv file has about 10mio rows, and three columns. Then Pivot reduces the redudency by storing date/id information uniquely in the row and column index. However, it ends up with about 10000-20000 columns.

Comment: The problem arises actually already when I append only two bigger pivoted tables. If I collect this two dataframes in a list (as suggested), concat them and then only pivot it is rather fast (cannot do this for the full list of files, due to memory constraints), but if I first pivot each table and then append/concat it runs undefinedly.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? (some random numbers that mimics the dataframe) Because if I try to concat two dataframes of 2000 rows x 10000 columns, that runs in less than a second.

Comment: I tried to simulate the data, have a look please, it should take some to concat this pivoted data-frames, (it highly depends on how many IDs are choosen to be in each file)

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference if I would assign integer column names and map them latter back, I would suspect that string comparison is slower than an int based index

Comment: Thanks for the example code! (you only forgot to add the imports) See my answer for a possible solution. Using integer names will not be needed, as the checking that the column names are equal or finding the union of them is not the bottleneck.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I added the imports

Answer (score 13):

Using your reproducible example code, I can indeed confirm that the `concat` of only two dataframes takes a very long time. However, if you first align them (make the column names equal), then concatting is very fast:

```
In [94]: df1, df2 = data[0], data[1]

In [95]: %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2])
1 loops, best of 3: 18min 8s per loop

In [99]: %%timeit
   ....: df1b, df2b = df1.align(df2, axis=1)
   ....: pd.concat([df1b, df2b])
   ....:
1 loops, best of 3: 686 ms per loop
```

The result of both approaches is the same.
The aligning is equivalent to:

```
common_columns = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)
df1b = df1.reindex(columns=common_columns)
df2b = df2.reindex(columns=common_columns)
```

So this is probably the easier way to use when having to deal with a full list of dataframes.

The reason that `pd.concat` is slower is because it does more. E.g. when the column names are not equal, it checks for every column if the dtype has to be upcasted or not to hold the NaN values (which get introduced by aligning the column names). By aligning yourself, you skip this. But in this case, where you are sure to have all the same dtype, this is no problem.
That it is *so much* slower surprises me as well, but I will raise an issue about that.

Comment: Thanks. I figured two things: First, when you replace the id_list with an integer index (simply add `id_list = range(0,num_ids)` instead of the simulated ids it has a massiv perfomance impact. Second, I realized I also had some errors codes in the raw data, so the dtypes was of type object, cleaning the data and using only floats increased perfomance also by a larger factor. The aligning as you suggest also increases perfomance but only when columns or of type string not as much anymore when you use integer columns. Maybe someone varifies this findings and it might be worth improving in pandas

Comment: Have you had a chance to have a look at my comment?

Answer (score 3):

Summary, three key performance drivers depending on the set-up:

1) Make sure datatype are the same when concatenating two dataframes

2) Use integer based column names if possible

3) When using string based columns, make sure to use the align method before concat is called as suggested by joris

Answer (score 1):

As @joris mentioned, you should append all of the pivot tables to a list and then concatenate them all in one go.  Here is a proposed modification to your code:

```
dfs = []
for file in raw_files:
    data_tmp = pd.read_csv(path + file, engine='c',
                           compression='gzip',
                           low_memory=False,
                           usecols=['date', 'Value', 'ID'])
    data_tmp = data_tmp.pivot(index='date', columns='ID',
                              values='Value')
    dfs.append(data_tmp)
del data_tmp
data = pd.concat(dfs)
```