# trying to read a large csv file and concat too slow

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, read.csv

I'm trying to read a large csv file(over 100 GB) 
I found the way to read the large csv file with chunksize option

```
%%time
import time
filename = "../code/csv/file.csv"
lines_number = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
lines_in_chunk = 100# I don't know what size is better
counter = 0
completed = 0
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=lines_in_chunk)
```

this part is great faster 
 
but the problem is concatenation

```
%%time
df = pd.concat(reader,ignore_index=True)
```

this took over 4hours and did not finish yet.
the ram memory usage is keep growing too

is there way to concat this reader file faster and efficiently?

Comment: I don't know much about pandas, but aligning dataframes apparently leads to a major speedup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860671/pandas-append-perfomance-concat-append-using-larger-dataframes

Comment: I think you'd need to use dask for a 100GB CSV, or load it into SQL to do your data prep. Recently ran into a similair problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can read files faster by first installing Dask with `conda install dask`. Then importing it via `import dask`. You will also need to import pathlib's Path, and pass filename like `Path('filename')`. You can then read the file like so: `dask.dataframe.read_csv(filename)`. Alternatively you could convert it in to a pickle file, read it with `pd.read_pickle(filename)` but converting it would involve reading it with pandas and then converting it with pandas.